# Redshift Spectrum and Hive Metastore - Ambiguous Error

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum, hive-metastore

From Redshift, I created an external schema using the Hive Metastore.  I can see the Redshift metadata about the tables (such as using: select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES), however when querying one of these tables, I get an ambiguous error "error:  Assert"

I tried creating the external schema and querying the tables.  I can query the metadata about the tables, but cannot actually query the tables themselves.

I created the external schema as follows:

```
create external schema hive_schema
from hive metastore
database 'my_database_name'
uri 'my_ip_address' port 9083
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my_role_name';
```

Here is the error message when running "select * from hive_schema.my_table_name;"

```
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   loc->length() > 5 && loc->substr(0, 5) == "s3://" -
  query:     1764
  location:  scan_range_manager.cpp:221
  process:   padbmaster [pid=26902]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i guess your hive meta is incorrect? does it work from elsewhere (hive/presto?) how did you create it?

Comment: @JonScott - yes, I can query the tables successfully from hive.

Answer (score 1):

What is the `LOCATION` of your Hive table? Seems like Redshift is *asserting* the location to start with `s3://`.

You should see `LOCATION`s of your tables by running that query:

```
select location from SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES
```

Where are your Hive tables stored? Is it maybe HDFS? I doubt whether Redshift supports any other locations than S3 - in the section *Considerations When Using AWS Glue Data Catalog* of [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html) they describe how to setup your Hive Metastore to store data in S3.

Comment: Great observation.  Yes, it was created as a HDFS based table.  I changed this to be an S3 bucket, which got rid of the error listed above, however I am now getting a timeout, even though this is currently a tiny table -- only 1 row and 1 column.   Any ideas why?

```
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch), retries exceeded
  code:      15001
  context:   S3 request timed out.
  query:     11397
  location:  dory_util.cpp:913
  process:   query0_126_11397 [pid=12636]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you query it with any other sql engine? Hive? Presto?

Comment: Since the data is in s3 you can create an external table over it using glue catalog (`CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA my_schema FROM DATA CATALOG ...` and then `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_schema.my_table() ... `) - just to test whether there's a problem with this bucket.